# mysqldump and --tab speed

Tags: mysql

According to the MySQL Certification Guide, when `--tab` option is used,

> a `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` is used to generate a tab delimited file in the specified directory, a file containing `SQL (CREATE TABLE)` will also be generated

and that

> using `--tab` to produce tab-delimited dump files is much faster

but how can it be faster if both generate a SQL file and the `--tab` one just has an extra tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that :

- without using `--tab`, a file is generated, that contains both :

  - `create` statements
  - and data, as lots of `insert` statements
- with `--tab`, two files are generated :

  - one with `create` statements
  - one other with data, in a tab-delimited format, instead of `insert` statements

The difference is the second part :

- `insert`s
- vs tab-delimited

I'm guessing that creating lots of `insert` statements takes more time than just dumping data with a tab-delimited format *-- maybe it's the same with importing the data back, too ?*

Comment: i will look forward to an asnwer for "maybe it's the same with importing the data back, too ?" maybe it has to do with the extra markup also?